# Download and show an image from a URL in background

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to download & show an image from a URL using asp.net

e.g. I have a page ShowImage.aspx
When I call this page it should show image(from Response Stream) from external URL
https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png

with Response.ContentType = "Image/png"

**SOLVED ON MY OWN**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png");
        WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        Byte[] buffer = null;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", response.ContentLength.ToString());

        int bytesRead = 0;
        do
        {
            buffer = new Byte[4096];
            bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
            }
        } while (bytesRead > 0);
        Response.End();
    }
```

REF: http://forums.asp.net/t/1401931.aspx/1

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/fetching-image-using-wcf-rest-service/

Comment: yes, but how to get file over http and send the stream to client as an image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use the [Image.ImageUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.imageurl.aspx) property of Image control

```
<asp:Image id="img1" runat="server" ImageUrl="https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png" />
```

If you want to set Image url from server side (code behind)

```
img1.ImageUrl = "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.imageurl.aspx";
```

If you use WebRequest to get the Image string from url.

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png");
WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
     ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
}
```

Comment: On the page I do not want to add any asp.net control, everything should happen in code behind

Comment: you added asp:Image control on page which i dnt wish to add

Comment: To show image you need asp:image or img html control, what else you need?

Comment: how to write the `stream` to `Response`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public Stream GetImage()
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            using(WebClient Client = new WebClient())
            {
               using(StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(Client.OpenRead("FILE URL")))
               {
                 try
                 {
                   string Contents = Reader.ReadToEnd();
                   Reader.Close();
                   return Contents;
                 }
                 catch
                 {
                    return string.Empty;
                 }
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How to do this in asp.net page?